# Change Visual Studio 2017 .props location file

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am new in visual studio 2017

I have imported a qt project file (.pro) and created a .vcxproj file with QtVSTools, my problem is that it generate a lot of intermediate files including  a

$(Configuration)/qmake/qtvars_(Platform)_(Configuration).props file.

My question is how to customize this file location to a desired eg.

$./build/(Configuration)/qmake/qtvars_(Platform)_(Configuration).props

I have already search for this customization in the project properties with no luck. 
I really appreciate your help in finding a solution.